# How can I upload the data to my p-multiSelect?

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm working with the primeNG component, but I can't load the data.

[MultiSelect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxNuC.png)

```js
this.listadoProductos = this.resolucionDatosCargados['listProduct'];
this.parametros['producto'] = this.listadoProductos;  
console.log(this.parametros['producto']);
```

```html
<!--MultiSelect-->
<h4>Grupo de producto</h4>
<div class="ui-fluid">
  <p-multiSelect  [options]="listadoProductos" [(ngModel)]="parametros.producto" optionLabel="descripcion"    defaultLabel="Producto" display="chip"></p-multiSelect>
</div>
```

This is the JSON object that it returns to me in the console.

[ [ 1, "Trigo " ], [ 2, "Maíz " ], [ 3, "Arroz " ], [ 4, "Otros granos " ], [ 5, "Aceites " ], [ 6, "Azúcar " ] ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you set `description` as `optionLabel`, but the data don't have this key.

Moreover, PrimeNG said this: [image]

`Options` should be an array of object. If the request give you this data, I recommend you to create an array of `SelectItem` objects.

```
var arrayProductos: SelectItem[] = [];
this.listadoProductos.forEach(productos => {
 arrayProductos.push({
   {label: productos[1], value: productos[1]}
  })
})
<p-multiSelect  [options]="arrayProductos" [(ngModel)]="parametros.producto" defaultLabel="Producto" display="chip"></p-multiSelect>
```

Maybe, this may be the error.